# Настройка нескольких URL на один и тот же файл

Tags: .htaccess, url

Страница сайта находиться по адресу: `http://example.com/news/`

**Необходимо настроить** `.htaccess` таким образом чтобы при переходе по ссылке: `http://example.com/article/` мы попадали в `http://example.com/news/`.

И при этом у пользователя в адресной строке был указан `http://example.com/article/` если он переходил по этой ссылке, у того, кто переходил по  `http://example.com/news/` соответственно `http://example.com/news/`.

В этом случае команда `Redirect` не подходит. Пробовал нечто вроде этого

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/news%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /mebel/$1    [L]
```

или так

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/mebel/$
RewriteRule /news/
```

Но ничего не хорошего не происходит. Видимо я где-то либо что то не прочел, либо что-то недопонимаю. Можете помочь?